# KFold Cross Validation Package/Library in C++?

Tags: cross-validation, c++

I need to do some cross validation work in C++. Is there any existing package/library that you'd recommend?

I performed a search on Google but prefer to get advice from field experts here.

Thank you for your time and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you will find that many of C++ libraries, listed in [this section](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#cpp-general-purpose) of that nice curated list of machine learning (ML) libraries, support cross-validation. Also, if you don't mind using C++ within .NET, check an interesting ML framework [Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net) - it indeed does support cross-validation.